# SharePoint 2013 and Outlook task synchronization without Exchange 2013?

Tags: tasks, outlook, exchange, synchronization

I have the following problem: I'm trying to synch a task list ("Synchronize with Outlook" button in the ribbon). With SharePoint 2010 this button would lead to a pop up from Outlook ("do you really want to synchronize"...) and I would be done - the task list will be synchronized with Outlook.

With SharePoint 2013 we now have the Work Management Service and [Exchange Task synchronization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554516%28v=office.15%29.aspx). I did set up the work management service application, but what I do not have is Exchange 2013 - hence task synchronization via Exchange wouldn't work (we have Exchange 2010).

Here is the question: When I click "Synchronize with Outlook" I get a new pop-up stating if I want to synchronize the list. When I click "yes" it is trying to synchronize, but I receive an error. I did not check ULS logs, but I'm assuming its trying to do this via Work Management Service & Exchange which can't work as I don't have Exchange 2013.

Can I go back to the "old way" of synchronizing task lists by just disabling / stopping the work management service application? Does the "old way" (clicking the synchronize button, Outlook directly starts) still exist or do I have to use Exchange 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old post but I will reply for incase someone is looking for the answer.

I see in the white papers there is a way to enable the legacy feature of syncing tasks.

Here is an extract:

"Legacy sync to Outlook SharePoint feature

The new "Sync to Outlook" feature replaces the legacy feature for all editions of SharePoint Server 2013 except for the Foundation SKU. This means that the feature will be installed on all non-Foundation deployments, regardless of the presence of Exchange Server 2013 in the topology. For the cases where Exchange Server 2013 is not going to be available, the administrator can disable the new Exchange Server integration feature to re-enable the legacy feature. With the feature disabled, behavior will revert to the legacy Outlook behavior from previous versions, which is found in the Foundation SKU as well." https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38799

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Welcome and great answer! Funny thing is that the work management service is deprecated already anyways...

Answer (score -1):

Exchange 2013 is a requirement in order to sync tasks between SharePoint and Outlook.  Refer:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554516%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Yes it is. Did you read my question? *"Can I go back to the "old way" of synchronizing task lists by just disabling / stopping the work management service application? Does the "old way" (clicking the synchronize button, Outlook directly starts) still exist or do I have to use Exchange 2013?"*